# Stripe-Metadata not in response (WebHook/.net-core)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, stripe-payments

I am using stripe for payments.
When I create the SessionCreateOptions object I add the CustomerId and ProductId for later usage in my Webhook.

```
 var options = new SessionCreateOptions
        {
            PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> {
                "card",
            },
            CustomerEmail = buyer.Email,
            LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions> {
                new SessionLineItemOptions {
                    Name = packages.First().Name,
                    Description = packages.First().Description,
                    Amount = (long)(totalAmount * 100),
                     Currency = "eur",
                    Quantity = 1,
               },
            },
            SuccessUrl = appSettings.RedirectHost.Url + "/Checkouts/Show/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
            CancelUrl = appSettings.RedirectHost.Url + "/Checkouts/Show/failed",
            Metadata = new Dictionary<String, String>()
            {
                 { "CustomerId", buyer.Id.ToString()},
                 { "ProductId", packages.First().Id.ToString()}
            },
        };
```

After a successful payment the webhook gets called and retrieves to object with customer data, price and other values, but the metadata dictionary is empty.

[image: stripe webhook response]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are retrieving the `PaymentIntent` that was created by the `CheckoutSession`, but you're setting the `metadata` on the `CheckoutSession` itself.

There are two options, depending on where you want to store and retrieve the metadata. You can retrieve the `CheckoutSession` directly [0], or you change your code to set the `metadata` on the `PaymentIntent` when creating the `CheckoutSession`, via `payment_intent_data.metadata` [1].

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata

Comment: Thanks!
I created  
var paymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions();

and added this to my SessionCreateOptions object

Comment: Thanks! Just in case someone is looking for subscription metadata, as I did, you need to store it in a similar way but under "subscription_data.metadata" that you can find in the same doc above